# cannot get jQuery slider to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

How does one get a slider working with jQuery.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='example1' class='ui-slider-1' style="margin: 40px;">
        <div class='ui-slider-handle'></div>    
</div>  

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-slider-handle {
    border:1px solid silver;
    height:10px;width:10px;
    background-color:black;
}

#example1 {
    width:1050px;
    background-color:white;
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#example1').slider( { minValue: -100, maxValue: 100 } );
```

Let me know if you need more code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add some jQueryUI styles to it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Also, you don't need to have `<div class='ui-slider-handle'></div>` inside the `div`, it's handled by jQueryUI.